# Top-down merge sort algorithm producing mismatched list

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I attempted to take the top-down merge sort algorithm from this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Top-down_implementation) and make it into C code, but the result doesn't produce correct results.

here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int A[10] = {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
int B[10]; //sorted array
int n;
void TopDownMergeSort(int A[], int B[],int n);
void TopDownSplitMerge(int B[], int iBegin, int iEnd, int A[]);
void TopDownMerge(int A[], int iBegin, int iMiddle, int iEnd, int B[]);
void CopyArray(int A[], int iBegin, int iEnd, int B[]);

int main()
{
    TopDownMergeSort(A, B, 10);
    for(int i = 0;i < 10;i++) {
        printf("%i ", B[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

// Array A[] has the items to sort; array B[] is a work array.
void TopDownMergeSort(int A[], int B[], int n)
{
    CopyArray(A, 0, n, B);           // duplicate array A[] into B[]
    TopDownSplitMerge(B, 0, n, A);   // sort data from B[] into A[]
}

// Sort the given run of array A[] using array B[] as a source.
// iBegin is inclusive; iEnd is exclusive (A[iEnd] is not in the set).
void TopDownSplitMerge(int B[], int iBegin, int iEnd, int A[])
{
    if(iEnd - iBegin < 2)                       // if run size == 1
        return;                                 //   consider it sorted
    // split the run longer than 1 item into halves
    int iMiddle = (iEnd + iBegin) / 2;              // iMiddle = mid point
    // recursively sort both runs from array A[] into B[]
    TopDownSplitMerge(A, iBegin,  iMiddle, B);  // sort the left  run
    TopDownSplitMerge(A, iMiddle,    iEnd, B);  // sort the right run
    // merge the resulting runs from array B[] into A[]
    TopDownMerge(B, iBegin, iMiddle, iEnd, A);
}
void TopDownMerge(int A[], int iBegin, int iMiddle, int iEnd, int B[])
{
//  Left source half is A[ iBegin:iMiddle-1].
// Right source half is A[iMiddle:iEnd-1 
    // While there are elements in the left or right runs...
    for (int k = iBegin; k < iEnd; k++) {
        // If left run head exists and is <= existing right run head.
        if (i < iMiddle && (j >= iEnd || A[i] <= A[j])) {
            B[k] = A[i];
            i = i + 1;
        } else {
            B[k] = A[j];
            j = j + 1;    
        }
    } 
    printf("Sort result 1: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%i ", A[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void CopyArray(int A[], int iBegin, int iEnd, int B[])
{
    for(int k = iBegin; k < iEnd; k++)
        B[k] = A[k];
}
```

Running this code on the given list produces the result `6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`, and in general running a given list produces a list with two sorted halves that aren't merged. I've tried to replicate the algorithm as faithfully as I can, but I can't seem to figure out where the problem arises.

Comment: You don't suppose that the implementation of `TopDownMerge()` might be even just slightly pertinent to the problem at hand?

Comment: Maybe you are just sorting array `A`, while array `B` is how it was sorted in step `N-1`

Comment: @MikeNakis the function def got eaten somehow; it's there now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the Wikipedia article has a bug.

In `TopDownMergeSort`, the line:

```
TopDownSplitMerge(B, 0, n, A);   // sort data from B[] into A[]
```

is wrong. `A[]` is the source, and `B[]` is the destination.  This is the corrected line of code:

```
TopDownSplitMerge(A, 0, n, B);   // sort data from A[] into B[]
```